# Inserting Grids and Graticules in ArcScene?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, 3d-analyst, arcscene, grids-graticules

I have searched Grids and Graticules option in ArcScene 10.3 but didn't found there. I am specifically interested to mark Y-axis (as in below map I've prepared in Surfer) to show vertical values of my DEM. How would I insert axis in ArcScene?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I do not know a way to do this in ArcScene, but if you wanted to add a grid to a 3D ArcScene image you could import it back into ArcMap and add the grid there. The steps would be:

1. Export your 3D image from ArcScene as a 2D image.
2. Open ArcMap. Add the original georeferenced layer. Then add the 2D .jpeg image exported from ArcScene as a new layer.
3. Georeference your .jpeg image onto the original layer.
4. In Layout View, turn off the original layer. Add the grid and rotate the map if necessary.

Comment: I think ArcScene 10.3 currently doesn't have facility to draw vertical and horizontal axis (grids and graticules) into its perspective view, even, you cant insert scale bar or legend into it. There is no option of layoutout. In, ArcMap planimetric view, there are multiple options to handle 2D data with customized grid and graticules. They should work to add such facilities which are common in other applications.